# C# LINQ left join 3 Tables/Lists

Tags: c#, linq, join, left-join

I am looking to join 3 tables which I am getting as List of objects. These are my three tables:

**Employee**

[image]

**Department**

[image]

**Category**

[image]

Employee DepartmentID and CategoryID is used to join Department and Category Table.

This is how my Linq Join looks

```
var result = from e in Employee.GetAllEmployees()
                         join d in Department.GetAllDepartments() on e.DepartmentID equals d.ID
                         join c in Cateory.GetAllCategories() on e.CategoryID equals c.ID
                         into eGroup
                         from c in eGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new
                         {
                             Employee =e,
                             Department = d ==null? new Department() : d,
                             Cateory = c
                         };
```

My issue here is that I am getting two different rows for Employee ID = 1 and that's because of two different Categories for ID =1

[image]

I would like to get both categories in the same Employee node. Basically two categories for Employee ID =  1.

Expected Result: 
CategoryA and CategoryB is tied to Employee Mark.

[image]

[image]

How do I achieve that?

Thanks for the help !

Here is the code to reproduce what I have so far.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = from e in Employee.GetAllEmployees()
                     join d in Department.GetAllDepartments() on e.DepartmentID equals d.ID
                     join c in Cateory.GetAllCategories() on e.CategoryID equals c.ID
                     into eGroup
                     from c in eGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new
                     {
                         Employee =e,
                         Department = d ==null? new Department() : d,
                         Cateory = c
                     };

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        public static List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
        {
            return new List<Employee>()
                    {
                        new Employee { EmployeeID = 1, Name = "Mark", DepartmentID = 1, CategoryID = 1 },
                    };
        }
    }

    public class Department
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

        public static List<Department> GetAllDepartments()
        {
            return new List<Department>()
                {
                    new Department { ID = 1, DepartmentName = "TECH"},
                    new Department { ID = 2, DepartmentName = "HR"},
                };
        }
    }

    public class Cateory
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public static List<Cateory> GetAllCategories()
        {
            return new List<Cateory>()
                {
                 new Cateory { ID = 1, CategoryName = "CategoryA"},
                 new Cateory { ID = 1, CategoryName = "CategoryB"},
                 new Cateory { ID = 2, CategoryName = "CategoryC"},
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to join on `Id` for all tables? That seems... not right at all. In a relational DB you normally use foreign keys or a new table if you have a many-to-many relationship. **Example**: An employee can work in 1 department but a department can have many employees that work there. This would then lead you to design a FK, lets call it DepartmentId, in the Employee table as a **new** column. Then you would create a query that joins on that or (better yet) model that relationship in your c# types.

Comment: @Igor ID is Employee table is the primary key and ID in other tables are serving as foreign key. I will change that in my example now

Comment: That still does not make sense though as how is a category linked to exactly 1 employee or how is a department name linked to exactly one employee. I would revisit your assignment/design and try to hammer out the entity relationships first. I would also select good names for your columns, ID is not a good name but EmployeeId would be especially if you want to reuse that same name in a relationship.

Comment: department can have many employees. I have just given a sample data.

Comment: Updated question with better column name and relationship between tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a way of testing this really but you should be able to do a left join by updating your query

```
 var result = from e in Employee.GetAllEmployees()
                 join d in Department.GetAllDepartments() on e.DepartmentID equals d.ID into d_def
                 from d in d_def.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join c in Cateory.GetAllCategories() on e.CategoryID equals c.ID into c_def
                 from c in c_def.DefaultIfEmpty())
                 select new
                 {
                     Employee =e,
                     Department = d ==null? new Department() : d,
                     Cateory = c
                 };
```

Comment: If you want to select all the categories then start with that in your query and left join from employee and department

Comment: Thanks. but I get two rows for employee ID  =1 , I am looking to get only one row. 

I have added expected  output.

Answer (score -1):

Here are your results.  The two employer have the same ID number

[image]

Comment: Then ZOOM with your browser and set to 150%